vue3 compile error:[plugin:vite:vue] [vue/compiler-sfc] Unexpected token, expected "," (21:13)
I make a vue application to use bpmnio/form-js-viewer, the official project url is here :
the source code page
There is an object structure error when I want to compile the App.vue file. Could someone make any suggestions, Thanks.
<template>
  <div id="form">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { Form } from '@bpmn-io/form-js-viewer'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    setup() {
      const schema = {
        components: [
          key: 'creditor',
          label: 'Creditor',
          type: 'textfield',
          validate: {
            required: true,
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>

The error information is below:

The package.json file is below:
{
  "name": "designer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "form designer software",
  "productName": "form designer app",
  "author": "besley",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "dev": "quasar dev",
    "build": "quasar build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bpmn-io/form-js-viewer": "^1.8.8",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.4.34",
    "axios": "^1.7.0-beta.2",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "mitt": "^3.0.1",
    "quasar": "^2.16.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.18",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vue-uuid": "^3.0.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app-vite": "^1.9.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^20 || ^18 || ^16",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
}


Components is meant as an object and should have curly braces ({}), but is declared as array, using brackets ([])

Hi, the source code is from the official project page: https://github.com/bpmn-io/form-js/tree/develop/packages/form-js-viewer, if it was changed to {}, it will make other function error by using this parameter.

It should be an array of objects:
<template>
  <div id="form"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { Form } from '@bpmn-io/form-js-viewer'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    const schema = {
      // there should be an '{' after '['
      components: [{
        key: 'creditor',
        label: 'Creditor',
        type: 'textfield',
        validate: {
          required: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
</script>


Hi, although the program can be compiled, but it will throw other error information caused by this object structure: Uncaught (in promise) Error: form field of type  not supported. I think it seemd that it is related with the vue3 enviorement.

That should be another issue, maybe you can provide a repo or reproduce it on an online env, e.g. stackblitz

Hi, please you can review this page: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6mnwg8?file=index.html

@BesLey Please check the example to see if any further support is needed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8av9zp?file=src%2FApp.vue

It works fine. It seemed that there is one parameter missing in the schema object. If the property 'type': 'default' is added, it will make sense. Thanks. Great Solution.
